# why can we access a non_member function from member function in c++

Tags: c++, class, scope, member-functions, non-member-functions

The following code compiles without any warning or error:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class demo_class
{
    int x;
    float y;
    public:
    void fun(void);
};
void fun2(void)
{
    cout<<"i am fun2\n";
}
void demo_class::fun(void)
{
    cout<<"i am fun\n";
    cout<<"i can call fun2\n";
    fun2();
}
int main()
{
    demo_class ob1;
    ob1.fun();
    return 0;
}
```

I am not understanding that as the scope of fun function is only in demo_class
then how can it call fun2 function, should not it show error as the access of fun function only within the demo_class?

Comment: where would you be able to call the function if not there?

Comment: `cout<<"..."` is also a function call - also from a different scope. Yet you're not surprised about it?

Comment: "scope of fun function is only in demo_class" true - you have called it on `obj1`. What it does inside it another matter. That function can call anything it has access to - including global functions like `fun2`.

Comment: If member function were only ever able to use each other, very little useful software would be written with C++. If any at all!

Answer (score 2):

[Name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup) would try to examine all the possible scopes, until it finds at least one at any scope, then the name lookup stops.

In this case, the name `fun2` can't be found at class scope, then the further scope, i.e. globle scope is examined and `::fun2` is found.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to disallow calling a free function from within a member function. If this was the case classes would be rather useless (they would be a way to prevent code reuse instead of supporting it).

As mentioned in a comment, in  `cout<<"i am fun2\n";` you are calling a non-member function and calling `fun` is not much different from that.

Further, with a grain of salt your example is not much different from

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class demo_class
{

};
void fun2(void)
{
    cout<<"i am fun2\n";
}
void fun3(demo_class& dc)
{
    cout<<"i am fun\n";
    cout<<"i can call fun2\n";
    fun2();
}
int main()
{
    demo_class ob1;
    fun3(ob1);
    return 0;
}
```

A member function can always be transformed into a free function. If `fun` would access private members we would have to declare it as `friend` to make the above work, but otherwise no problem here.

You can also do the reverse and call member functions in free functions as in

```
 struct foo {
     void bar(){}
 };

 void func(foo& f) { 
      f.bar();
 }

 int main() {
     foo f;
     func(f);
 }
```